# Self Extraction Directive file comment?

Tags: syntax, comments, iexpress

I'm using IExpress 2.0 to create the deployment for my Visual Studio project, and it has generated an SED file that I'd like to document.

What's the syntax for me to place a comment inside the SED file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SED files share the same syntax as [INI files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file). As such, you can place comments in them by prefixing the comment with a semi-colon. Comments can also be placed at the end of lines using the same mechanism.

An example:

```
[Version]
Class=IEXPRESS
SEDVersion=3
[Options]
;this is a comment
PackagePurpose=InstallApp ;this is another comment
ShowInstallProgramWindow=0
......
```

**NOTE:** If you then edit the SED file using IExpress, it does keep comments that you have added (so long as you then re-save the SED file when done), **but only those that are on a line of their own** - comments at the end of lines are lost.